# JavaScript not writing variable as number (loop)

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop

I have a javascript code like this and this always gives me a problem

```
    for(var i=1;i<9;i++){
        document.getElementById('element'+i).onclick=function(){
             theFunc(i)
        }
    }
```

It selects the right element and adds the onclick. But, when I type in console  `document.getElementById('element1").onclick` it returns `theFunc(i)` (not `theFunc(1)`)

So no matter which element is clicked it will always call `theFunc(9)` (at the end i is 9)

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: Found it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example possible duplicate.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: We should have that in our bookmarks, really. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I've added them [to the tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/javascript/info).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your event handler function has an *enduring reference* to `i`, not a copy of its value, as you've discovered.

To prevent that, have the function close over something else that won't change:

```
for(var i=1;i<9;i++){
    document.getElementById('element'+i).onclick=makeHandler(i);
}

function makeHandler(index) {
    return function() {
        theFunc(index);
    };
}
```

`makeHandler` creates a function that closes over `index`, which is a copy of the *value* of `i`, and so doesn't change as the loop continues. Each event handler gets its *own* `index`.

That said, creating a bunch of event handler functions that are effectively identical usually means you can redesign a bit and use just one handler function. In this case, for instance, you could do this:

```
for(var i=1;i<9;i++){
    document.getElementById('element'+i).onclick=theHandler;
}

function theHandler() {
    func(parseInt(this.id.replace(/\D/g, ''));
}
```

...which grabs the value to use from the `id` of the element.

Another approach is *delegation*, where you actually hook the `click` event on an ancestor element (one that all of these elementX's have in common), and then when the click occurs, look at `event.target` and its ancestors to see what you should do.

Comment: You are great T.J. Crowder

Comment: Although it's limited in support and messed up the order of parameters, you could also use `.bind()`: http://jsfiddle.net/Cs8Mb/ . I'm not sure I'd recommend it for this situation, but it works

Answer (score 1):

TJ Crowder's answer is the best way around your problem. This "problem" you're experiencing in your closure is by design in many languages, and is referred to as scope.

Here's a good explanation of different scopes in JavaScript (including closures) and how to use them.
http://robertnyman.com/2008/10/09/explaining-javascript-scope-and-closures/

Answer (score 0):

When you say `theFunc(i)` you are creating a closure around `i`, such that every function call refers to the same variable. You need to wrap the function inside an outer closure to ensure each function call is working with a unique variable:

```
for(var i=1;i<9;i++){
  (function(i){

    document.getElementById('element'+i).onclick=function(){
         theFunc(i);
    }

  })(i);
}
```

Comment: I can't see why this is downvoted. However, note that creating a new *builder* function on every loop iteration is not best practice (you have to create a new event handler, but you're actually creating two functions on each loop, the builder function and the event handler function.) Also, I always recommend using a *different* name for the argument, for clarity.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I think you just explained why it deserves a downvote. This also suffers from the fact that it closes over all other local variables, not allowing them to be GC'ed. Your answer doesn't allow that, which is great.

Comment: @Ian - Assuming there are other local variables, of course...

Comment: @JustinEthier Of course, I was just pointing it out :)